# Convert.ToDateTime Works in console app but errors out in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Convert.ToDateTime works in console app,

```
string a = "18/02/2015";
DateTime aa = Convert.ToDateTime(a);
```

Errors out in asp.net forms saying string is not righ format,

```
DateTime aa = Convert.ToDateTime(myTextBox.Text);
```

It used to work before, but since I got a newly installed server it started giving me this error..

Input string seem same to me "18/02/2015"

Comment: please check your system datetime format. I think its depend on your system date-time settings. pass date as per your system settings then it will be work.

Comment: I already added the exception of saying string is not right format.. Google will never answer me for why code works on console and why it doesn't in asp.net, give it a go and pass a single result to me

Comment: Have you mistakenly unaccept my answer? Or is there any mistake in my answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Convert.ToDateTime` uses `DateTime.Parse` internally, with the ***current culture of server***. And, the problem is your new server's current culture's `DateTime` format is different from your string.

You can use [`DateTime.ParseExact()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead of this.

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific
>   format information. The format of the string representation must match
>   the specified format exactly.

```
DateTime.ParseExact(myTextBox.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```